# Assign a byte array to a 2 dimensional byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, variable-assignment, type-2-dimension

I want to assign a byte[] to a byte[][] but it gives me the run-time error :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

this is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfChunks; i++)
{
    byte[][] myFile = new byte[NumberOfChunks][];
    myFile[i][0] = buffer[i]; // IT STOPS HERE AND GIVES ME THE ERROR
    if ((i + 1) == NumberOfChunks)
    {
        do sth....
    }
}
```

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

[][] is an array of arrays unlike [,].

So allocating first dimension you'll get just array of null pointers to possible arrays.

Try this:

```
byte[][] myFile = new byte[NumberOfChunks][];
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfChunks; i++)
{
    myFile[i] = new byte[NumberOfItems];
    myFile[i][0] = buffer[i]; // IT STOPS HERE AND GIVES ME THE ERROR
    if ((i + 1) == NumberOfChunks)
    {
        do sth....
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a start, but OP has misused `i` - so the code above is still quite wrong. [Not the point you were making; just saying people should not copy the above blindly.] I recommend having *three* index variables: `iIn` to step through input, `iItem` to step through elements of one output row or chunk, and `iChunk` to step through the chunks. Details left to the reader. :)

Answer (score 1):

`myFile[i][0]` is null because you only allocated the first dimension. At the beginning of your loop, the array looks like this:

`myFile -> [null, null, null, ...]`

You can allocated the other dimension by iterating over your array:

```
byte[][] myFile = new byte[NumberOfChunks][];
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfChunks; ++i)
{
    myFile[i] = new byte[NumberOfChunks];
}
```

The result will be:

`myFile -> [byte[], byte[], byte[] ...]`

So `myFile[i]` will be pointing to one of the `byte[]` instead of a null reference.

As a side note, you can use a 2d-array `byte[,]` in order to allocate the two dimensions at the same time. Just be aware that the performances are not equivalent.